# Proving there are an infinite number of irreducible monic polynomials over a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory

I was given this problem, and the solution I came up with is eerily similar to the classic Euclid proof on infinitude of primes, so I'm feeling like I must be wrong somewhere.

**Problem**: Given $k$ any field, show that there are infinitely many irreducible monic polynomials in $k[X]$.

**My attempt**: assume there are finitely many irreducible monic polynomials $f_1, f_2, ..., f_n$. Then consider $p = 1 + f_1 f_2 ... f_n$, which is monic since all the $f_i$ are monic and $1$ is constant. By assumption, $p$ must be reducible, since it is not equal to any of the $f_i$. So there must exist some $g \in k[X]$ such that $g$ divides $f_1 f_2 ... f_n$ -- a contradiction since the $f_i$ are assumed to be irreducible.

I think my mistake was in assuming $p$ is not equal to any of the $f_i$ -- I suppose in some finite field perhaps there is a case where that could be... I'm trying to work out in my head whether that's possible.

Am I on the right track or just totally off?

TIA!

Jason

EDIT: should be that one of these $f_i$ must divide $p$, since $p$ is reducible, but that's not possible because then they would have to divide 1.

Comment: Although I prefer the kind of argument given by @CMonsour below, I think many people like your kind of proof exactly because it looks like the traditional one based on Euclid.

Comment: Why do you think it's wrong? Euclid's proof works because of divisibility properties, prime and irreducible elements, and a certain product construction. The generality of why his proof works can extend to where you have those things.

Comment: No one said it was wrong.  It's just nicer to have a proof that gives a more pleasant, less haphazard, infinite collection.  It also just depends on what you know.  If you know the structure of finite fields, the other proof is more direct.  But a proof that uses that $k[X]$ is a UFD is fine.  It's not quite properly stated in the question, though, so I figured it might be easier for the questioner to think about it a different way.

Answer (score 4):

It's easier than that, actually.

If $k$ is infinite, there are an infinite number of monic linear polynomials, and they are all irreducible.  If $k$ is finite, $k$ has infinitely many finite extensions (corresponding to adjoining the appropriate roots of unity), and each extension has a generator which has a monic minimal polynomial over $k$ and these are all distinct and all irreducible.  QED

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand why the proof being similar to the classic Euclid proof on infinitude of primes would cause you to wonder if it is wrong. I do not find this similarity to be surprising since the statements being proved are similar.

I think your proof is close. Once you get to the step where $1+f_1\cdots f_n$ is reducible, then you can say that one of the $f_i$ (which is of degree $>0$) divides it.

Also, add that there exist an irreducible polynomial since $x$ is irreducible.

Comment: I see what you mean. Since it's reducible, it's a product of irreducible polynomials, hence at least one of the $f_i$ must divide it, but it can't because of the 1. Got it. But what do you mean in your last comment about there existing an irreducible polynomial -- what is $x$ in that context? Thanks!

Comment: $x$ is an irreducible polynomial. There argument takes a finite (but non-zero) number of irreducible polynomial and shows that there is another one. So, for your argument to work, you need at least one irreducible polynomial.